# elasticsearch nested query which every item in nested obj have same value of some key

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to select doc which the albumId of each item of imageList is 1.

Current index mappings:

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "groupId": {
      "type": "keyword"
    },
    "imageList": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "imageId": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "albumId": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I ingest the following data into an index:

```json
[
  {
    "groupId": 1,
    "imageList": [
      {
        "imageId": 11,
        "albumId": 1
      },
      {
        "imageId": 12,
        "albumId": 1
      },
      {
        "imageId": 13,
        "albumId": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupId": 2,
    "imageList": [
      {
        "imageId": 21,
        "albumId": 1
      },
      {
        "imageId": 22,
        "albumId": 2
      },
      {
        "imageId": 23,
        "albumId": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupId": 3,
    "imageList": [
      {
        "imageId": 31,
        "albumId": 3
      },
      {
        "imageId": 32,
        "albumId": 2
      },
      {
        "imageId": 33,
        "albumId": 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "groupId": 4,
    "imageList": [
      {
        "imageId": 41,
        "albumId": 1
      },
      {
        "imageId": 42,
        "albumId": 1
      },
      {
        "imageId": 43,
        "albumId": 1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is my query:

```json
{
  "size": 500,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "imageList",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "imageList.albumId": 1
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "adjust_pure_negative": true,
      "boost": 1.0
    }
  }
}
```

It doesn't work, get `groupId = 1` `groupId = 2` `groupId = 4`,but expect `groupId = 1` `groupId = 4`

Comment: Well, but your doc with `groupId = 2 ` has a subdocument with `albumId = 1`. Query works correctly. :|

Comment: yeah,the query works correctly,but query in wrong way

Comment: I see it now. Cheers!

Comment: While not accepted, this one seems to have some insightful details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043805/searching-objects-having-all-nested-children-matching-a-given-query-in-elasticse

Comment: thx! It seem not in any efficient way.You must count all imageList and compare to how many item match . For more details: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/19166

Comment: I think the only real way to solve this would be remodeling your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a must_not clause with [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html). Try out the below search query -

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "imageList",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "imageList.albumId": [
                        2,
                        3,
                        4
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "imageList",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "imageList.albumId": 1
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "65771795",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "groupId": 4,
          "imageList": [
            {
              "imageId": 41,
              "albumId": 1
            },
            {
              "imageId": 42,
              "albumId": 1
            },
            {
              "imageId": 43,
              "albumId": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "65771795",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "groupId": 1,
          "imageList": [
            {
              "imageId": 11,
              "albumId": 1
            },
            {
              "imageId": 12,
              "albumId": 1
            },
            {
              "imageId": 13,
              "albumId": 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: thanks a lot.The range of albumId is not fixed.In fact, there are thousands of value it couled be, and would be more.It is not flexible